# Python and Elasticsearch API changes and Autcomplete

Tags: python, curl, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

So to begin. I am trying to add around 7.2k documents. No problem there. The issue is after I am not able to get any suggestions returned to me. So this is how the information is added:

```
 def addVariantToElasticSearch(self,docId, companyId, companyName, parent, companyIndustry, variants, count,conn):
    body = { "company":{
                 "company_name": companyName,
                 "parent": parent,
                 "suggest": {   "input": variants,
                                "output": companyName,
                                "weight": count,
                                "payload": {"industry_id": companyIndustry, 
                                            "no_of_jobseekers":count,
                                            "company_id": companyId
                                           } 
                             }
                         }
            }
     res = conn.index(body=body, index="companies", doc_type="company", id=docId)
```

The mapping and settings is defined as:

```
def setting():
 return { "settings" : {
                "index": {
                   "number_of_replicas" : 0,
                   "number_of_shards": 1
            },
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_edge_ngram_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
                        "filter":["standard", "lowercase"]
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "edgeNGram",
                        "min_gram" : "1",
                        "max_gram" : "5",
                        "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
                "company" : {
                  "properties" : {
                        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
                        "industy": {"type": "integer"},
                        "count" : {"type": "long" },
                        "parent": {"type": "string"},
                        "suggest" : {
                          "type" :     "completion",
                          "index_analyzer": "my_edge_ngram_analyzer",
                          "search_analyzer": "my_edge_ngram_analyzer",
                          "payloads": True
                        }
                  }
                }
          }
    }
```

Index creation:

```
def createMapping(es):
      settings = setting()
      es.indices.create(index="companies", body=settings)
```

I call `createMapping` which uses `setting()`, then add each variant - surrounded by a try,except -> causes no issue. I can see all my documents added in the browser as well as looking at the status, settings and mappings.

But when I use a curl request as below, I get no results. (See curl and output beneath)

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/companies/_suggest -d '
{ 
 "company-suggest" : { 
    "text" : "1800", 
    "completion" : { 
       "field" : "suggest" 
     } 
   } 
 }'

{

  "_shards" : {

    "total" : 1,

    "successful" : 1,

    "failed" : 0

  },

  "suggest" : [ {

    "text" : "ruby",

    "offset" : 0,

    "length" : 4,

    "options" : [ ]

  } ]
```

I am currently using ES 1.1.0. I have tried both Python API 0.4 and 1.1.0 with no luck (I tried 0.4 as a result of 1.1.0 not working although I know it isn't best to due to compatibility issues with version of ES). I have also been able to add the same settings with mappings via curl and added a company which I have been able to retrieve by this curl above.

I'm not sure exactly where the issue lies. I have looked at the Data folder in ES to ensure it has been created, as well as the browser. I have also ensured only a single ES instance is running.

Any help greatly appreciated,